# Put animated GIF in overlay over MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get this seemingly simple task to work.
I need to put an animated gif in an overlay on a mapview.

I have the following code:

```
AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.explosion);
```

However how do I now pop that in an overlay and throw it over the mapview?

Currently, to put static images I have this:

```
class DrawableIcon extends ItemizedOverlay {
    private ArrayList mOverlays = new ArrayList();
    public DrawableIcon(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

    }
    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }
    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {

        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

}
```

Which I then use as such: (gp is the geopoint of the spot I want to put the image in)

```
DrawableIcon image = new DrawableIcon(this.getResources().getDrawable(ResourceID));
image.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(gp, "", ""));
mapOverlays.add(image);
```

So how would I go about modifying this code so that when ResourceID is the ID of an animated gif image, the gif image would play it's animation over the mapview?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

To display an animation over map you can use addView method of MapView class. But layout params of the view must be initialized with MapView.LayoutParams.

In this case the View will automatically move when you scroll the map!

It is as simple as:

1. just create a view (like ImageView or any other View);
2. initialize the view layout, create and pass MapView.LayoutParams to setLayoutParams method;
3. add the view to MapView.

   ```
   public static void addAnimationToMap(MapView map, int animationResourceId, GeoPoint geoPoint) {

       final ImageView view = new ImageView(map.getContext());
       view.setImageResource(animationResourceId);

       //Post to start animation because it doesn't start if start() method is called in activity OnCreate method.
       view.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) view.getDrawable();
               animationDrawable.start();
           }
       });

       map.addView(view);

       MapView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new MapView.LayoutParams(
           MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           geoPoint,
           MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
       view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

   }
   ```

Comment: can you give more code or example,if i used the same code can add many views to the mapview,

Comment: pengwang, yes, you can use the code many times to add many views. It is similar to adding a view to any container, but when you add a view to MapView, you specify MapView.LayoutParams with GeoPoint (location) to which this view should be bounded.

Comment: As you can see from my answer, you must post animationDrawable.start() only in case if you add ImageView with animation during Activity onCreate execution. But if you add new animation to map view afterwards, you can call animationDrawable.start() right after calling view.setImageResource(). I hope it's clear.