# Android, How to make animated overlay on map?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

Please guide me how to do animated marker/ pin/ overlay icon on map.
I tried lot from last 2 day but i am not getting success.

Thanks in advance..

**Not working**

res/drawable/map_marker.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ecall_lowon" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ecall_mediumoff" android:duration="200" />
```

**Java code**

```
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_marker);
    MapItemizedOverlay mapItemizedOverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    GeoPoint geoPoint1 = new GeoPoint((int)(9.982878 * 1E6), (int)(76.285774 * 1E6));
    GeoPoint geoPoint2 = new GeoPoint((int)(9.973928 * 1E6), (int)(76.276824 * 1E6));

    OverlayItem overlayItem1 = new OverlayItem(geoPoint1, "Title1", "");
    OverlayItem overlayItem2 = new OverlayItem(geoPoint2, "Title2", "");

    mapItemizedOverlay.addOverlayItems(overlayItem1);
    mapItemizedOverlay.addOverlayItems(overlayItem2);

    mapView.getOverlays().add(mapItemizedOverlay);
```

But not getting success...

Comment: you should describes your question and add code///

Comment: @SamirMangroliya, i added the code please check now..

Comment: @visheshchandra the below answer really helped you which you accepted?

Answer (score 5):

An animation defined in XML that shows a sequence of images in order (`<animation-list /`>) may not work to show blink pin on map

I have work around this and find one of the solutions

**Idea:** Two drawables.., `Runnable` and `handler`, **SetPin_On()** and **SetPin_Off()**, In SetPin_On method use one image and in SetPin_Off method use another image,on each function calling  clear overlay and add again

**Resources:** Take two images say pin_on, pin_off

**Coding:** Runnable with handler is required to set the pins in intervals

Example:

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
      int check=0;

          Runnable r=new Runnable()
          {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
             if(check==0)
             {
               SetPin_On();
               check=1;

             }
             else if(check==1)
             {
               SetPin_Off();
               check=0;
             }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }

    };
```

And in **SetPin_On** method set the pin_on image on overlay and in **SetPin_Off** method again set pin_off image by clearing previous overlay

**SetPin_On:**

```
void SetPin_On()
    {
         mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
         mapOverlays.clear(); 

         res =getResources(); 
         drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_on);
         itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable,this, mapView);


         point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(lati)*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(longi)*1E6));
         overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello", "I'm in Athens, Greece!");

         itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
         mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

         mapController = mapView.getController();

         mapController.animateTo(point);
         mapController.setZoom(6);
    }
```

**SetPin_Off:**

```
void SetPin_Off()
    {

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
         mapOverlays.clear(); 

         res =getResources(); 
         drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_off);
         itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable,this, mapView);


         point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(lati)*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(longi)*1E6));
         overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello", "I'm in Athens, Greece!");

         itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
         mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

         mapController = mapView.getController();

         mapController.animateTo(point);
         mapController.setZoom(6);

    }
```

This is one solution to get blinking pin.May not efficient  but result is very accurate

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052830/put-animated-gif-in-overlay-over-mapview/7667842#7667842) for another solution